# the meaning of straining in the sentence

Tags: word-meaning

The text says: "Some men seem to be obsequious in association with others and in interchange of words and deeds. They praise everything for the sake of pleasantness, and never contradict anyone, being of the opinion that unpleasantness ought to be avoided."

My question lies here in the commentary: "He says that in human conversation and generally in all human companionships some seem to be obsequious, as it were *straining* to please men. They praise everything that others say and do for the purpose of making themselves aggreeable."

Is the word "strain" here an intransitive verb?
According to MW, then the meaning would be "3. to make a great difficulty or resistance" so as to stress the extent that it appears to be very difficult to please men therefore some seem to be obsequious.

Did I understand it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: as if, not as it.

Comment: I double-checked my book, it is "..., as it were straining ..."

Comment: What book, what century? Sounds like Dickens or something.

Comment: Aristotle's Nicomachean Ethics. Book 4 Chapter 6
I guess the subject confuses me.

Comment: So, it is a translation.  I still think it should be if and not. It **can be a typo**.  to strain means to make a great effort physically or mentally to do something.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible to be a typo. So will strain always follow someone/some animals instead of *it*?
All of the examples on [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/strain) have someone or living creatures as the subjects.

Comment: strain is a verb or a noun. But "a conversation" or a "relationship" cannot strain [transitive verb] to do something. A person can strain his muscles making an effort.

Comment: The style of the translation is archaic - I would guess it's several hundred years old. Nowadays we would say _Some people seem to be obsequious, as though they were making a great effort to please others_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's definition 1.1 at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/strain):

Verb [*no object*] Make an unusually great effort.

> *‘his voice was so quiet that I had to
> strain to hear it’*

So it says, "...some seem to be obsequious, as it were making an enormous effort to please men."

It could be written:

'...as if they were making an enormous effort to please men."

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. It makes sense to me.
Though I am still confused about the subject regarding the definition. So the subject could either be someone or it, right?

Comment: The subject is "someone"; "[as it were](https://www.lexico.com/definition/as_it_were)" is a standard phrase meaning something similar to "approximately" or "sort of".

Comment: The subject is "_some_". It's a pronoun. It can mean "some people". It's like, "Will he be re-elected? Some say he will, some say he won't." "Do they like Marmite? Some do." Second definition of the pronoun at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/some).

Comment: @StuartF 
I feel it finally makes sense to me. 
[as it were](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20it%20were): as if it were so: in a manner of speaking;
So the subject of straining is some[someone]. 
Problem solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

"He says that in human conversation and generally in all human companionships some seem to be obsequious, *as if it* were straining to please men. They praise everything that others say and do for the purpose of making themselves agreeable."

Translations are very tricky especially of Ancient Greek.

To do something **as if** doing something else.

I was playing my music as if playing for money.

If you strain to please someone it means to make a great effort to do so.

There is actually *some sort of translation error* here because a conversation can be strained (difficult to have) but a conversation cannot "strain".

Also, it is possible that the pronoun it refers to something from a previous paragraph.

Comment: The use of straining in the text seems to be a little bit weird.
Thanks for your help. I will take note of your explanation.